# Git push pull is a headache

Tags: git, cvs

I'm a Git enthusiast. Our company has been using CVS for Version Control for over a decade. I tried to convince my colleagues to switch to Git to overcome the limitations of CVS.

One of my seniors pointed out a situation where CVS is better than Git (Really!). Let me tell you the situation.

Suppose John, Bill, Harry and Tom are working on the same repository but all in separate functionalities and at one point, John and Bill modify the same Utility file.

In this situation, John tries to push his changes. Meanwhile, Bill already pushed his changes. So, John has to pull the changes first, merge them and then try to push again.

Now, Harry pushes his changes. So, John has to redo the pull-merge-push activity again.

Again, Tom pushes his changes. And John failed to push his changes 3 times but never succeeded because somebody else pushed their changes before he could.

This situation will not appear in CVS because we can commit changes to a set of files without updating the whole repository.

So my question is, how do companies with large number of developers use Git? What is the workaround for this [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_%28computer_science%29) problem?

Comment: They shouldn't usually be working in the same branch even. And if they are merging their feature branches, of course they need to pull the newest versions. So it's not really a problem. And of course you should merge everything in the branch and test it before pushing, so is there really a problem? People usually want to push things without checking there aren't other changes done that affect them?

Comment: Did your question get resolved ?  Please select a answer as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that situation can and *does* occur in CVS, it is just (significantly) rarer because such conflicts occur at the file level.  More specifically, CVS has *file atomicity*.

In practice, collisions of this sort are rare in Git because (as other answers already note) we use branches to enable better parallel development.  In addition, in all those cases where CVS would not have a collision (because the changes are in separate files), Git (or equivalently Mercurial) will easily do the merge or rebase all on its own, so that in your case, John may have to retry `git fetch && git rebase && git push` once or twice,<sup>1</sup> but since he can do this quite trivially (e.g., with <kbd>CTRL-P</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the shell), it turns out to be no burden at all.  Finally, in those cases where you *do* get a collision in CVS, you generally have to resolve that collision immediately.  With a DVCS like Git, you can defer the resolution as long as you want by tossing it into a branch instead (Mercurial makes this decision harder because branches are persistent and global).

I quote from my own book-in-progress below...

<sup>1</sup>In fact, `git fetch && git rebase` has a convenience shortcut, `git pull --rebase`.  Not much shorter, is it? :-)  You can configure `git pull` to *automatically* rebase, so that it becomes `git pull && git push`, but that is something you should not do until you are very familiar with fetch-and-rebase.

---

#### Centralized vs distributed

Many older VCSes are *centralized*, or CVCSes. Git and Mercurial are DVCSes: *distributed* version control systems.

The key difference between these two kinds of systems is that a centralized VCS has a designated master repository. There may be multiple copies of the master, or even multiple masters with some kind of synchronization protocol (e.g., ClearCase MultiSite), but there is only one master. Their design assumes this single-master-ship and thus is allowed to depend on it.

With a distributed VCS, there is no designated master repository. Users generally have a complete, private copy of each repository. Communications between these private copies are, at least in principle, peer-to-peer operations: neither repository is any more masterful, and conflicts—situations where both Alice and Bob have made changes to the same regions of the same files—can and do occur and require some kind of resolution.

It’s always possible to use a distributed VCS in a centralized manner: you simply designate one particular repository as the master version, and coordinate updates to it. However, centralized systems
 often provide features like locking source files or directories, restricting access (for read and/or write, to particular files, directories, and/or branches), and so on. With a typical DVCS it’s more difficult (though not technically impossible) to provide these, and Git and Mercurial simply don’t, at least not without add-ons. With CVCSes that provide locking, users may lock files (typically just one specific version ID) to prevent other users from making conflicting changes. This is conceptually easier, but of course it can prohibit parallel work.

#### Repositories and work-trees

VCSes distinguish between the repository (where files are well-controlled and versioned) and the work-tree (where files are usually not versioned). The work-tree is typically where you edit the files, compile them, and otherwise work with them. [snip rest of paragraph, which fleshes out some earlier definitions]

With a centralized VCS, the master repository can be left on a centralized server. We can then checkout to a work-tree on the user’s machine (e.g., a laptop) without first copying the entire repository,
so the laptop’s storage can be smaller than the server’s. Typically we can also extract only a small subset: if the repository contains hundreds of packages, libraries, or other subsystems, we can check out just one subsystem, or even just one file. This is convenient when
one is just making a quick and easy change. On the other hand, it requires that the work-tree be connected (networked) to the centralized server during checkout and checkin/commit operations, and if the local workspace is disconnected, other revisions may not be available.

Since distributed VCSes usually copy the entire repository,<sup>5</sup> the entire history is normally available at all times. The main tradeoff here is longer setup times for the initial copy (the *clone* operation), and additional non-volatile storage needed for the clone. These DVCSes work hard to make synchronization operations efficient, so that once you have the initial clone, obtaining new versions is relatively fast. (For instance, I have seen initial clones that take four or more hours over slow networks, but their resynchronizations usually take only a few seconds.)

---

<sup>5</sup>Both Git and Mercurial now support *shallow clones* and *single-branch clones*, which can omit some of a repository. [snip rest of footnote, which is basically a teaser for upcoming information later, or maybe a link to it, eventually...]

#### Atomicity: what is the smallest unit of revision?

Older VCSes work with just one file at a time, using the check-out / check-in model. Their unit of atomicity is the *file*. Even if you check out (or in) many files at once, the VCS just does each operation on
a per-file basis, as if you had done them one at a time. Consider the four buildable iterations shown in Table 1.1. Let’s assume that at each iteration, a new set of compile-able files were all checked in together—but our VCS only works with files, one file at a time. Every file starts out as version 1, but at iteration 3, file `kanga.c` has two versions, while file `roo.c` has three.<sup>6</sup> The last buildable iteration introduces the new file `wallaby.c`, which is now at version 1. Which versions of which files do you need in order to build any given iteration? Which file-version combinations do you need to skip? The answer is in our table, of course, but the VCS does not track this on its own.

<sup>6</sup>For the moment, we will just number each file revision, without worrying about making trees out of the revisions.

[Tables 1.1 and 1.2 require markup not available in StackOverflow; here I use plain text]

---

Table 1.1: Four buildable iterations, recorded with file atomicity, resulting in seven check-ins.  The file actually checked-in on each row is marked with an asterisk.

```
check-in iteration                   files
--------------------------------------------------------
    1                 kanga.c:1*
    2       1         kanga.c:1   roo.c:1*
    3                 kanga.c:2*  roo.c:1
    4       2         kanga.c:2   roo.c:2*
    5       3         kanga.c:2   roo.c:3*
    6                 kanga.c:3*  roo.c:3
    7       4         kanga.c:3   roo.c:3   wallaby.c:1*
```

---

Newer systems, including Git and Mercurial, work on larger sets of files. Their unit of atomicity is the *commit*. Committing a change enters all the files at once. If anything goes wrong, *no* files get a new revision; if the entire commit succeeds, *all* files get a new revision, as shown in Table 1.2. Extracting the latest commit—row 4—gets you the latest version of all three files. Backing up one version gets you the previous `kanga.c` and `roo.c`—this changes the contents of `kanga.c` while keeping the contents of `roo.c` the same—and removes `wallaby.c` entirely, all automatically.

---

Table 1.2: The same four buildable iterations, but with commit atomicity.

```
commit                    files
------------------------------------------
   1     1:kanga.c   1:roo.c
   2     2:kanga.c   2:roo.c
   3     3:kanga.c   3:roo.c
   4     4:kanga.c   4:roo.c   4:wallaby.c
```

---

Generally, in file-atomicity systems you can name or *tag* a set of file-revisions that go together, and extract by tag. Tags tend to have
a noticeable cost—even if they don’t use a lot of space or time,<sup>7</sup> they present a sort of revision clutter, and in practice they’re used only for more-major checkpoints. Commit-based systems obviate the need for these tags (though as we will see, tags are still useful).

<sup>7</sup>Tags in CVS, for instance, are maintained on a per-file level, so that tagging an entire tree is a very slow operation.

[Much more snippage, removing entire sections on compression, file identity, branching and version numbering, some philosophical issues regarding the separability of branches and revisions, etc.]

#### Concurrency model

Whether centralized or distributed, any VCS that lets multiple users work independently of each other must offer some method for dealing with potential conflicts. As mentioned earlier, one method is *locking*: before changing a file, the user must obtain a lock, which is then released upon committing the change. This simple method has the obvious problem mentioned earlier of prohibiting parallel work. It’s possible to make the locks finer-grained—Alice might lock the top half of the file, leaving the bottom half available for Bob to lock and change—but this has scaling issues. In addition, users and/or administrators must have ways to break locks since users will lock files but fail or forget to unlock them (e.g., after deciding not to commit).

If the VCS provides a *merge* model, two or more people may work on the same files, and at defined rendezvous points—in a CVCS, at check-in / commit time, for instance—they are given a chance to reconcile their changes. Merges are also needed when combining branches, and in modern DVCSes, the same methods are generally used for both of these.
Note that in a DVCS, the rendezvous point (and hence any merging) can occur after checkin. Bob may be able to pick up Alice’s work before doing his own checking-in, but because the system is distributed, Bob does not have to wait for Alice (nor vice versa).

[The next section is a review of selected VCSes.  I will not copy it here, but will note that I gave CVS an entry in the table that shows it as one step up from SCCS and RCS: it has merge concurrency, but still uses file atomicity and is not distributed.  Subversion is in the next group, giving commit atomicity and merge concurrency, but still uses a centralized repository.  Meanwhile Git and Mercurial both use commit atomicity, merge concurrency, and use the fully distributed model.

There are reasons to stick with centralized VCSes, but anyone still using CVS today should probably have switched to SVN years ago.  Commit atomicity is such a leap ahead that I, at least, would never go back if I can avoid it.  SVN has a weird branching model but it does work, and there are cvs2<thing> converters to help you out here.]

Answer (score 3):

To begin with i am not sure i understand how `CVS` handles the scenario of two users updating the same utility file better than `GIT`.

In any code repository the standard practice is to update your code and then push out your changes so that you do not accidentally step on some one else's work or inadvertently overwrite someone else's work..

In standard git workflow the following would happen.
Suppose i work on a feature branch `branch_a` based off of `develop` branch.

i would do the following,

i.On the `develop` branch execute : `git checkout -b branch_a`

ii.Make my changes on `branch_a` 
At this point i am sure of the changes i need to make. However the `develop` branch i am working against could have been updated by other users.

iii.So i do a : `git pull --rebase origin develop`
This updates my local branch against the current `develop` branch.
If someones has indeed pushed out changes that conflict with yours you will get a conflict here itself. You can resolve them at this point.

iv.After this step your branch is ready for getting merged to develop.

v.You can now merge your branch into develop by checking out the develop branch and doing a `git merge branch_a`.

Git is different from most older systems in the way that you make commits locally on your local branch as opposed to the older way of making commits to the repo at a go. To me Git's approach is far cleaner and safe when it comes to maintaining repos with large number of users.

Comment: You are correct. CVS will force us to update the file and retrieve others' changes before committing our own. I guess the question needs to be altered to point out that in CVS one doesn't have to update the whole working copy to push change to a single file (or set of files) which nobody else changed.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Som Bhattacharyya (I haven't got enough rep to comment): I would have John, Bill, Harry and Tom working closely together. By the time John notices he can't push because Harry pushed something, he'd call out to the guys and they would tune into eachother.

The alternative would be 4 developers, each in their own kingdom fighting to push their changes.

To help my colleagues transition to Git (from SVN mainly) I said the following 2 things:

1. Remember, in Git, branches are cheap. Cheap. Branches.
2. Please read [the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

After this we were able to come up with a workflow that works very well for us, preventing exactly the kind of problem you are having.

Update: writing this answer and some things going on at work today made me realise even more that for us, the most important thing still is communication rather than strictly conforming to a workflow. I dare say this goes for every team, or not?

Comment: I deliberately left out the details of the workflow we use, because there are some very good 'standard' workflows to start from. The Pro Git book I mentioned provides examples, but you can also read [Atlassians view on workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/centralized-workflow) or ['Git Flow'](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (but then also read [this](http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful)). There's much more to find on the topic. Our workflow is suited to our specific needs and evolved as such.